# Passing multiple Parameters in single Azure Storage Script for various environments

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I have a powershell script that creates the storage and blob account for a given subscription that works fine . Subscription Name, resource group keeps changing for different environments like DEV,UAT,PROD

STRUCTURE OF MY TEMPLATE / CODE :

```
param(

 [string] $subscriptionName ="ABC",
 [string] $resourceGroupName = "XYZ",
 [string] $resourceGroupLocation ="westus",
 [string] $templateFilePath = "template.json",
 [string] $parametersFilePath = "parameters.json"
)

Function RegisterRP {
    Param(
        [string]$ResourceProviderNamespace
    )

    Write-Host "Registering resource provider '$ResourceProviderNamespace'";
    Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace $ResourceProviderNamespace;
}

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$confirmExecution = Read-Host -Prompt "Hit Enter to continue."
if($confirmExecution -ne '') {
    Write-Host "Script was stopped by user." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    exit
} 
# sign in
Write-Host "Logging in...";
Login-AzureRmAccount;

# select subscription
Write-Host "Selecting subscription '$subscriptionName'";
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName;

# Register RPs
$resourceProviders = @("microsoft.storage");
if($resourceProviders.length) {
    Write-Host "Registering resource providers"
    foreach($resourceProvider in $resourceProviders) {
        RegisterRP($resourceProvider);
    }
}

#Create or check for existing resource group
$resourceGroup = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if(!$resourceGroup)
{
    Write-Host "Resource group '$resourceGroupName' does not exist. To create a new resource group, please enter a location.";
    if(!$resourceGroupLocation) {
        $resourceGroupLocation = Read-Host "resourceGroupLocation";
    }
    Write-Host "Creating resource group '$resourceGroupName' in location '$resourceGroupLocation'";
    New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location $resourceGroupLocation
}
else{
    Write-Host "Using existing resource group '$resourceGroupName'";
}

# Start the deployment
Write-Host "Starting deployment...";
if(Test-Path $parametersFilePath) {
   New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $deploymentName -TemplateFile $templateFilePath -TemplateParameterFile $parametersFilePath -storageAccounts_name $storageAccountName
} else {
   New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $deploymentName -TemplateFile $templateFilePath; -storageAccounts_name $storageAccountName
}
```

Approach 1 : 
Created multiple powershell scripts for each denvironment 
Created 1 Menu Based powershell script that calls the other script and executes like : Select 1 for Dev , 2 for UAt , 3 for PROD , this approach works but is not effective .

Approach 2 :

I would like to combine all scripts and just have one script for all environments and based on select should allow me to create the storage accounts. Only Subscription and resource group change rest all structure of the powershell remains same .

I tried using GET function commandlets and it selects but still throws the error

```
 [string] $subscriptionName = Get-AzureSubscription,
 [string] $resourceGroupName = Get-AzureRmLocation,
```

If i try to use it using an array based approach like passing the values as below im unable to understand how do i pass these array based values to the code and get it to work .

```
$environment=@('DEV','TEST','QA','PROD')
$resourcegroupname = @('test','test1','test2','test3')
$subscriptionName = @('devsub1','devsub2','test3','prod4')
```

I'm trying to call the functions using :

```
$environment[0]
$subscriptionName[0]
```

It returns the value as below if i execute it seperately but how do i pass these values to my script to create storage account ?

```
DEV 
devsub1
```

Requesting expert help if anyone has come across such scenarios earlier and if you can help in changing the above code and provide a tested code that would be of great help.

APPROACH 3:

```
$subscription = @(Get-AzureRmSubscription)
$resourcegroup = @(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup)
$Environment = @('DEV','TEST','QA','PROD')
$resourceGroupName = $resourcegroup | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Pick the environment'
$subscriptionName = $subscription | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Pick the subscription'

Write-Host "Subscription:" $subscriptionName
Write-Host "ResourceGroup:" $resourcegroup
```

OUTPUT : 
If you look at resource group it fails to give the selection option for resource group .

Subscription: < it returns the subscription name > 
ResourceGroup: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.PSResourceGroup Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmd
lets.SdkModels.PSResourceGroup Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.PSResourceGroup Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Res
ourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.PSResourceGroup

Comment: `$grp = Get-AzResourceGroup | Out-GridView  -PassThru` works for me. same as: `Get-AzSubscription | Out-GridView  -PassThru`

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing is an interesting approach.  I would likely an input parameter that defines which environment the work will be done in, and then have a conditional block that sets the dynamic variables for that environment.  There would be some duplication of initialization code for each environment, but the main code block would still be unified.

Comment: adding inputs parameters works fine but how do i call the conditional block within parameters ?